# Filter ObjectModel in DelegateModel in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I wonder if it is possible to somehow use an `ObjectModel` as the model for multiple `DelegateModel` to use it's ability to create Groups.

For example, I might have an `ObjectModel` containing multiple `Rectangle` as this

```
ObjectModel {
    id: rootModel
    Rectangle { width: 50; height: 20; color: 'red' }
    Rectangle { width: 80; height: 50; color: 'blue' }
    Rectangle { width: 50; height: 20; color: 'green' }
    Rectangle { width: 80; height: 50; color: 'orchid' }
    Rectangle { width: 50; height: 20; color: 'black' }
}
```

My goal might be to display all `Rectangle` with the `width: 50` in one View, while those with the `width: 80` in another view.
So I create a `DelegateModel`

```
DelegateModel {
    id: delMod1
    model: rootModel

    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup { name: 'width50' },
        DelegateModelGroup { name: 'width80' }
    ]
}
```

As far as I understood the documentation I need to attach the property

```
item.DelegateModel.inWidth50: ....width === 50
item.DelegateModel.inWidth80: ....width === 80
```

or something like this, to add my elements to the groups. But this is where I fail as I don't know where and how to do this.

Though there are tons of workarounds (such as disassembling the Objects in the `ObjectModel` and using a ListModel, recreating the Objects in the `DelegateModel` delgate, which robbs a lot of the versatility as the Objects and it's children would need to have a predictable structure...) I think it would be wonderful, if it is possible to make this idea run.

Takk fyrir,
-m-

Comment: I guess that using [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#details) is good idea for this case.